# How to automatically mount S3 bucket right after connecting to EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs, goofys

Usually everytime I connected(`start` or `restart`) my instances I have to manually
mount the S3 bucket to it. I do it with the following command using [Goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) (or alternatively s3fs)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-00-23-230:~$ ./go/bin/goofys mybucket my_mountdir
```

Is there away I can automatically mount it everytime I login to my instances

Answer (score 3):

With Linux you automatically mount the drives using `fstab`; which requires special drivers for different filesystems.

You should install the `fuse` drivers and add entry for s3 bucket in `/etc/fstab`

**Update**

There is a new open source project simplifying the things https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

Comment: should I install it in instance or my local directory?

Comment: The FSTAB configuration should be done on the instance

Answer (score 2):

Create a new script in /etc/init.d/mountbucket

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/mountbucket
```

write the line you want to execute :-

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/ubuntu/go/bin/goofys mybucket my_mountdir
```

make it excutable

```
sudo chmod ugo+x /etc/init.d/mountbucket
```

update to start in each system restart

```
sudo update-rc.d mountbucket defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

goofys' README addressed this use case: https://github.com/kahing/goofys/

In short:

> To mount an S3 bucket on startup, make sure the credential is
>   configured for root, and can add this to /etc/fstab:
>
> `goofys#bucket   /mnt/mountpoint        fuse     _netdev,allow_other,--file-mode=0666    0       0`